# ansible get environment variables to used as vars

Tags: ansible

guys. I want to use some environment variables that create in the shell by an export command like this

`export TOKEN=xxxxx`
`export USER=xxxx`

so I want to use these environment variables I created in my ansible playbook like

```
- name: login
  command: USER="variable I created" TOKEN="same as USER" python xxx.py
```

I check out the document env module but I can't understand the only one example. so I come for help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is to use [`environment:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-environment-and-working-with-proxies):

```
- name: login
  command: python xxx.py
  environment:
    USER: "variable I created"
    TOKEN: "same as USER"
```